# Gundam episode with scientists sealed in outer space, oxygen turned off

Tags: cartoon, episode-identification, mobile-suit-gundam, toonami

Around 10 years ago, I was watching Cartoon Network (Toonami) and I saw a scene from an episode of what I believe to be one of the *Gundam* series. In that scene, a half dozen or so older scientists were sealed in some sort of room in outer space (ship? space station?), and the oxygen was turned off, and they were left there to die. I have no idea what happened before or after that.

Comment: Do you remember any names? what the gundam looked like? describe the quality of the drawings. 10 years ago. maybe it was either G-Gundam or gundam seed series.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like episode 24 of *Gundam Wing*, originally aired in 1995.

Wufei, Duo, and the Gundam Engineers are in a cell, and a enemy cuts off their air supply during a coup.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mobile_Suit_Gundam_Wing_episodes):

> Quatre, now mentally unstable, appears in the newly-constructed Wing Gundam Zero and begins to destroy various colonies one by one. Lady Une sends Heero and Trowa to fight back in the Mercurius and Vayeate, while Tsuborov, finding Une's behavior to be too lenient, stages a coup against her and cuts off the air supply to Wufei, Duo, and the Gundam engineers' cells.

Comment: Thank you. I looked up that episode, and then seeing as the scene wasn't resolved, I looked up episode 25. The scene I remember is, I think, the one that's seven minutes into that episode. Maybe my memory is bad and it's both episodes (although I don't remember ever watching a full episode of Gundam, let alone two of them). Whichever one it is, I'm really glad to have resolved this.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like side story, *Mobile Suit Gundam SEED C.E. 73 Stargazer*, part of the timeline of *Gundam SEED Destiny*. Here is the episode, if it's the one you're looking for.