# Do I need to watch the Gundam series in order to not be lost?

Tags: suggested-order, gundam-wing

I previously asked about a specific scene and found out that it was from Gundam Wing. [1]

I'm now considering watching that series, but I'm concerned that I'm not going to know what's going on if I jump straight into Gundam Wing without watching all of the previous series. I've been told that there are more than two dozen series, plus movies, and I don't have the time to watch everything.

Can I start straight with Gundam Wing without being lost? If not, which series should I watch first, or where can I read 'catch-up' material?

[1] [Which episode of which Gundam anime is the scene that's burned in my brain from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40334/which-episode-of-which-gundam-anime-is-the-scene-thats-burned-in-my-brain-from)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. *Wing* falls under the [AC](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/After_Colony) (After Colony) Gundam universe. Which includes just the anime and the *Endless Waltz* movie.

The main Gundam universe considered by most fans is the [UC](http://gundam.wikia.com/wiki/Universal_Century) (Universal Century) universe, which started with the original Gundam anime.

Check out [this](http://kotaku.com/5920413/the-gundam-multiverse-is-huge-and-confusing-and-were-here-to-help/) Kotaku article for a summary of the different universes and if they're your cup of tea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can watch wing, in all honesty they kind of sum up what's happened before, but I don't think that it really matter. I personally wouldn't know I just started watching the fundamental series, but I think you can just watch wing